# MD5 Original Value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using md5 function I get this result

```
SELECT md5('Hello')

Returns 8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7
```

What query can I use to do the reverse and see that value '8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7' is actually 'Hello' ?

I tried to use decode and decrypt unsuccessfully.

Comment: There is no query to do it. MD5 is a hash function and hash functions are not reversible. I'll see if I can find a dupe.

Comment: hi as explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5, MD5 is a one way hash function, it's not possible.

Comment: MD5 (and other hash functions) are explicitly designed to **prevent** what you're trying to do.

Comment: @easleyfixed specifically, collision avoidance is broken, but the Wikipedia page says that as of 2009, preimage (which is what this question is about) is still computationally infeasible.

Comment: If you would like to try possible input that generate outputs, you might have luck searching for "rainbow tables".